# Default preamble for AUCTeX latex-preview (like in LaTeXTools in Sublime Text)

Tags: emacs, auctex, latextools

I have a question: I've started using Emacs+AUCTeX for writing LaTeX documents. And I want to know whether there is any possibility for latex-preview to use some predefined preamble like LaTeXTools for Sublime Text does. In the AUCTeX manual, I've found that it can use 'texheader.tex' if it doesn't find any other preamble, but I can't get it working.

It would be especially useful while working with large documents, splitted in several files.

Many thanks!